# Sql Query for retrieve data from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables tb1(Uid,address,LoginTime),tb2(id,Uid,Name),tb3(Id,Uid,Name). tb1 have a primary key Uid .. both the other tables contains the foreign key .i need all the details from
tb1. based on the logintime i want to retrieve name from tb2 or tb3.. the Logintime is unique. it only contain tb2 or tb3 not in both...

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far ..

Comment: You want to retrieve logintime from tb2 or tb3, but you can't because it's in tb1... what?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT tb1.Uid, Address, LoginTime, COALESCE(tb2.Name, tb3.Name) Name
  FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2
    ON tb1.Uid = tb2.Uid LEFT JOIN tb3
    ON tb1.Uid = tb3.Uid
 WHERE LoginTime = ?
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5705c/3)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Can u please elaborate the last sentences of the question what i get

```
     SELECT tb1.*, tb2.Name, tb3.Name 
  FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2
    ON tb1.Uid = t2.Uid LEFT JOIN tb3
    ON tb1.Uid = t3.Uid
 WHERE tb1.LoginTime = ?
```

it will get all the data from tb1. but it will get the null values against the tb2.name,and tb3.name